# how to change font of firefox ui?

Tags: firefox

I have changed the font of viewing websites in firefox within the Option->Content tab, then the font of the UI is also changed. But I want to change it back, is there a way to do this?

Comment: What version of Firefox are you using? I'm using 4.0 beta, and it isn't changing the UI. Also, are you trying to just change the webpages or just change the whole thing back to default?

Comment: 3.6.10;I'm trying to just change the webpages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

userChrome.css would do the job.

Comment: Yup. Just do a simple Google search on "userchrome.css font" and you should get tons of useful tutorials.